# Laravel define updated_at type column

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a way to define a column as "updated_at" behaviour in Laravel?

I am currently updating an existing code, and it has updated_on defiend as column to store row-update timestamps. But it is, as expected, not working, since the column name must be "updated_at" for laravel functionality to work.

Is there any way to override or define updated_on column to update timestamp by default. Else code can always be written to update the column, but using default functionality would be a cleaner approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update the column value in the Eloquent model class, as below:

```
class YourModel extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The name of the "created at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CREATED_AT = 'created_on';

    /**
     * The name of the "updated at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_on';

}
```

Hope this helps you !